# How to create CloudWatch Alarm if an IP address is sending morethan threshold number of packets in a given time period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I want to create a CloudWatch Alarm if any IP address is sending packets more than 1000 in 10 minutes.

I have tried creating the below query to see the data, but want to automate it.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
  | filter srcAddr not like "10.0.1."   
  | filter interfaceId in ['eni-673617397YRDS','eni-24830HHDKF75G']
  | filter action = "ACCEPT"
  | stats count() as packetCount by srcAddr
  | sort packetCount desc
  | limit 10
```

I also tried to create a filter in VPC flow log, but not successful.

Comment: What prevented you from creating CloudWatch Metric filter?

Comment: I am able to create a metric filter for VPC flow log group with srcAddr as dimension. But the problem is the srcAddr is not static, and I am trying to create an alarm if any srcAddr crosses 1K packets in 10 mins.